# XML reading with proper error handling (line numbers, original text etc)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

I want to read a fairly large xml file. Its small enough to fit in memory, but still very big. When reading the XML it is validated against an XSD. This, however, does not prevent business errors from happening when using the read data for further manipulation in the system. When such  business errors occur (after XSD validation) I want to be able to describe the **line number** and **column number** for the start and end position of an element from my xml. Also, in this context, it would be user friendly to show the **input xml** as it was read from the file.

Using the **xsd.exe** I've code generated all the data classes and I read the xml using

```
  using (var reader = new StringReader(content))
  {
    var errors = new List<string>();
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.Schemas.Add("urn:import-schema", "Import.xsd");
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += (o, args) => errors.Add(args.Message);
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
    {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImportRoot));
      var result = (ImportRoot) xs.Deserialize(xr);
      if (errors.Any())
        throw new Exception(string.Join("\n\n", errors));
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't seem to find the meta-info that I'm looking for. I've checked the `XDocument` class as well. Here elements seems to have a `Value` property that is a string. But that is still not all the information I want to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line number information is not read from a `StringReader`. If you use a `StreamReader` on a `FileStream`, you'll be able to get the line number.

This additional metadata you're looking for is called the ["Post Schema Validation Infoset"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29#Post-Schema-Validation_Infoset).

Comment: It is not. The information would be available in the validation exception object.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I have been able to get this information when using a StreamReader on a FileStream.

Comment: And that information only gets populated after schema validation. You are looking for the "Post Schema Validation Infoset".

Answer (score 0):

In your ValidationEventHandler look at the args.Exception property. It is a [XmlSchemaException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception.aspx) type, that contains line number etc.

You could keep all the errors and then parse them afterwards.

```
var errors = new List<ValidationEventArgs>();
....
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (o, args) => errors.Add(args);
```

Business validation errors can be handled by implementing them as custom xslt functions. See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx). Once you have a function that implements [IXsltContextFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etf7ez2f.aspx) you can examine the XPathNavigator in the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.ixsltcontextfunction.invoke.aspx) method for a *hint* about where in the document you are.

Once you have the hint you can compare it with each line in the original document.

I did something like that a couple of years ago (besides the line numbers) and it worked very nicely. Even for large xml documents.

Comment: But its NOT schema validation problem! Its business validation after the xml has been read and validates fine against the XSD.

Comment: Ok, understood. Can you specify a business validation rule as an example?

Comment: sure. Say you do a product import, and the SKU (the product id) must be unique. then you can have a valid xml but one containing products already existing in the system which you are importing into.